# How can I send several parameters from jquery to my Controller as one single entity?

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid in my application.

This is my Read method

```
public virtual ActionResult ReadItems([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string Landbouwernummer = "", string Startjaaraanvraag = "", string Maatregel = "",
                    string Pakket = "", string Startjaarverbintenis = "", string Eindjaarverbintenis = "",
                    string Aanvraagtype = "", string Status = "", string Opmerkingen = "", string Lijst = "")
                {
                    List<AanvragenZoekenViewModel.ZoekResultaat> resourceItemsList = new List<AanvragenZoekenViewModel.ZoekResultaat>();
                    AanvragenZoekenViewModel.ZoekCriteria zoekCriteria = new AanvragenZoekenViewModel.ZoekCriteria
                    {
                        Landbouwernummer = Landbouwernummer,
        ...
                    };


                    return Json(resourceItemsList.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
```

And this is the jquery method to get adittional data

```
function onReadAdditionalData() {
    return {
        Landbouwernummer : $("#Landbouwernummer").klantenControl().getAlvNummer().toString(),
        Startjaaraanvraag : $("#Startjaaraanvraag").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
        Maatregel : $("#Maatregel").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
        Pakket : $("#Pakket").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
        Startjaarverbintenis: $("#Startjaarverbintenis").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
        Eindjaarverbintenis : $("#Eindjaarverbintenis").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
        Aanvraagtype : $("#Aanvraagtype").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
        Status : $("#Status").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
        Opmerkingen : $("#Opmerkingen").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
        Lijst : $("#Lijst").data("kendoDropDownList").value().toString()
    };
}
```

I'm no very good on Jquery, so this is my problem.

I need to turn this

```
public virtual ActionResult ReadItems([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string Landbouwernummer = "", string Startjaaraanvraag = "", string Maatregel = "",
string Pakket = "", string Startjaarverbintenis = "", string Eindjaarverbintenis = "",
string Aanvraagtype = "", string Status = "", string Opmerkingen = "", string Lijst = "")
{
...
}
```

into this

```
public virtual ActionResult ReadItems([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, AanvragenZoekenViewModel.ZoekCriteria zoekCriteria)
                {
...
}
```

How can I then turn this

```
 function onReadAdditionalData() {
        return {
            Landbouwernummer : $("#Landbouwernummer").klantenControl().getAlvNummer().toString(),
            Startjaaraanvraag : $("#Startjaaraanvraag").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
            Maatregel : $("#Maatregel").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
            Pakket : $("#Pakket").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
            Startjaarverbintenis: $("#Startjaarverbintenis").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
            Eindjaarverbintenis : $("#Eindjaarverbintenis").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
            Aanvraagtype : $("#Aanvraagtype").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
            Status : $("#Status").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
            Opmerkingen : $("#Opmerkingen").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
            Lijst : $("#Lijst").data("kendoDropDownList").value().toString()
        };
    }
```

into this

```
 function onReadAdditionalData() {
        return {
            **just one object**
        };
    }
```

That is, how can I send Landbouwernummer, Startjaaraanvraag, etc, as one single entity, whatever that is??

Comment: function already returns an object and you can pass that object to ajax methods directly. Really not clear what your issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out myself. It was a question of mapping variables.

```
public virtual ActionResult ReadItems([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, AanvragenZoekenViewModel.ZoekCriteriaPostModel zoekCriteriaPosted)                {
List<AanvragenZoekenViewModel.ZoekResultaat> resourceItemsList = new List<AanvragenZoekenViewModel.ZoekResultaat>();
AanvragenZoekenViewModel.ZoekCriteria zoekCriteria = new AanvragenZoekenViewModel.ZoekCriteria
{
    Landbouwernummer = zoekCriteriaPosted.Landbouwernummer,
    ...
};
return Json(resourceItemsList.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }


 function onReadAdditionalData() {
        var zoekCriteria = {
                Landbouwernummer: $("#Landbouwernummer").klantenControl().getAlvNummer().toString(),
                Startjaaraanvraag: $("#Startjaaraanvraag").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
                Maatregel: $("#Maatregel").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
                Pakket: $("#Pakket").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
                Startjaarverbintenis: $("#Startjaarverbintenis").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
                Eindjaarverbintenis: $("#Eindjaarverbintenis").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
                Aanvraagtype: $("#Aanvraagtype").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
                Status: $("#Status").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
                Opmerkingen: $("#Opmerkingen").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(),
                Lijst: $("#Lijst").data("kendoDropDownList").value().toString()
            };

        return {
            zoekCriteriaPosted : zoekCriteria
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a form in your aspx or cshtml page with some id="myForm"

also create a class which includes all those fields that the form contains for input.

then use the following code in your script:

```
$.ajax{(
    url:"contorller/action",
    data:$("#myForm").serialize(),
    type:"get/post",   // use one
     )};
```

And on server side do this:

```
public void method(MyModel m)
{}
```

Here model m is the model for all values which are coming from aspx or cshtml form page.
also use html helpers for associating model field to text box ie:
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.myfield);